# Kotlin Coroutines - cannot return object from room db

Tags: kotlin, asynchronous, android-room, kotlin-coroutines, android-livedata

I'm not super sure what I'm doing here so go easy on me:

I'm making a wordle clone and the word that is to be guessed is stored as a string in a pre-populated room database which I am trying to retrieve to my ViewModel and currently getting:

```
"StandaloneCoroutine{Active}@933049a"
```

instead of the actual data.

I have tried using LiveData which only returned null which as far as I'm aware is because it was not observed.

Switched to coroutines which seemed to make more sense if my UI doesn't need the data anyway.
I ended up with this so far:

DAO:

```
@Dao
interface WordListDao {
    @Query("SELECT word FROM wordlist WHERE used = 0 ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1")
    suspend fun readWord(): String

// tried multiple versions here only string can be converted from Job

//  @Query("SELECT * FROM wordlist WHERE used = 0 ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1")
//  fun readWord(): LiveData<WordList>

//  @Query("SELECT word FROM wordlist WHERE used = 0 ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1")
//  fun readWord(): WordList
}
```

repository:

```
class WordRepository(private val wordListDao: WordListDao) {

    //val readWordData: String = wordListDao.readWord()

    suspend fun readWord(): String {
       return wordListDao.readWord()
    }
}
```

model:

```
@Entity(tableName = "wordlist")
data class WordList(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    val id: Int,
    val word: String,
    var used: Boolean
)
```

VM:

```
class HomeViewModel(application: Application) : ViewModel() {

    private val repository: WordRepository
    private var word: String

    init {
        val wordDb = WordListDatabase.getDatabase(application)
        val wordDao = wordDb.wordlistDao()
        repository = WordRepository(wordDao)
        word = viewModelScope.launch {
                repository.readWord()
            }.toString()
        Log.d("TAG", ": $word") // does nothing?
    }
    println(word) // StandaloneCoroutine{Active}@933049a
}
```

This is the only way that I have managed to not get the result of:

```
Cannot access database on the main thread
```

There is a better way to do this, I just can't figure it out.

Comment: You’re missing fundamental concepts having to do with coroutines. It is too complex a topic to figure out by trial and error. I recommend you read through the official introductory documentation and make sure you understand it before attempting to use coroutines.

Comment: Is there a simpler workaround for now or is that my best option?

Comment: To avoid coroutines (which I don’t recommended because they make your code so much easier to write and read once you understand them) is to make your DAO functions return LiveData and remove the `suspend` modifier. Assign that live data to a property, and then other things that depend on it can be LiveData that use LiveData Transformations on it. The below answers explain a little bit, but if you just copy code without understanding it, that’s cargo cult programming.

Comment: Yeah I'm trying not to just copy anything and have it work, I want to understand it too. Otherwise it's a bit pointless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access the return value of `repository.readWord()` only inside the launch block.

```kotlin
viewModelScope.launch {
    val word = repository.readWord() 
    Log.d("TAG", ": $word")           // Here you will get the correct word
}
```

If you need to update you UI when this word is fetched from database, you need to use an observable data holder like a `LiveData` or `StateFlow`.

```kotlin
class HomeViewModel(application: Application) : ViewModel() {

    private val repository: WordRepository
    private val _wordFlow = MutableStateFlow("")  // A mutable version for use inside ViewModel
    val wordFlow = _word.asStateFlow()            // An immutable version for outsiders to read this state

    init {
        val wordDb = WordListDatabase.getDatabase(application)
        val wordDao = wordDb.wordlistDao()
        repository = WordRepository(wordDao)
        viewModelScope.launch {
            _wordFlow.value = repository.readWord()
        }
    }
}
```

You can collect this Flow in your UI layer,

```kotlin
someCoroutineScope {
    viewModel.wordFlow.collect { word ->
        // Update UI using this word
    }
}
```

**Edit:** Since you don't need the word immediately, you can just save the word in a simple global variable for future use, easy.

```kotlin
class HomeViewModel(application: Application) : ViewModel() {

    private lateinit var repository: WordRepository
    private lateinit var word: String

    init {
        val wordDb = WordListDatabase.getDatabase(application)
        val wordDao = wordDb.wordlistDao()
        repository = WordRepository(wordDao)
        viewModelScope.launch {
            word = repository.readWord()
        }
        // word is not available here, but you also don't need it here
    }

    // This is the function which is called when user types a word and presses enter
    fun submitGuess(userGuess: String) {
        // You can access the `word` here and compare it with `userGuess`
    }
}
```

The database operation will only take a few milliseconds to complete so you can be sure that by the time you actually need that original word, it will have been fetched and stored in the `word` variable.

Comment: The UI itself doesn't need to use the data, but multiple functions in the Viewmodel do. It's possible I'm going about this completely wrong

Comment: Maybe it is easier to give a better solution if you show the full viewModel or a pseudo code of what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @JoePleavin So, you are creating a Wordle clone. In that case, I guess you don't need the value of the word immediately when the game starts (viewmodel is created), you will only need it when user makes a guess, correct?

Comment: That's correct. It's actually only when they press enter, thinking about it like that, I could use livedata, observe the data in the UI and then pass the word to the functions from there when enter is pressed..

Comment: @JoePleavin I have edited the answer. See if it helps.

Comment: Yep this is it. I was naming the Job istelf as the variable I just needed the repository function. fml. Thanks so much.

Comment: I would switch from lateinit to a nullable var as it protects you if somehow the submit function is called before the query is finished.

Comment: @DanielKnauf We can check if a lateinit has been initialised or not by using `::word.isInitialized()` function

Answer (score 2):

(Now that I'm at a computer I can write a bit more.)

The problems with your current code:

- You cannot safely read from the database on the main thread synchronously. That's why the `suspend` keyword would be used in your DAO/repository. Which means, there is no way you can have a non-nullable `word` property in your ViewModel class that is initialized in an `init` block.
- Coroutines are *asychronous*. When you call `launch`, it is queuing up the coroutine to start its work, but the `launch` function returns a Job, not the result of the coroutine, and your code beneath the `launch` call continues on the same thread. The code inside the `launch` call is sent off to the coroutines system to be run and suspend calls will in most cases, as in this case, be switching to background threads back and forth. So when you call `toString()` on the Job, you are just getting a String representation of the coroutine Job itself, not the result of its work.
- Since the coroutine does its work asynchronously, when you try to log the result underneath the `launch` block, you are logging it before the coroutine has even had a chance to fetch the value yet. So even if you had assigned the result of the coroutine to some String variable, it would still be null by the time you are logging it.

For your database word to be usable outside a coroutine, you need to put it in something like a LiveData or SharedFlow so that other places in code can subscribe to it and do something with the value when it arrives.

SharedFlow is a pretty big topic to learn, so I'll just use LiveData for the below samples.

One way to create a LiveData using your suspend function to retrieve the word is to use the `liveData` builder function, which returns a LiveData that uses a coroutine under the hood to get the value to publish via the LiveData:

```
class HomeViewModel(application: Application) : ViewModel() {

    private val repository: WordRepository = WordListDatabase.getDatabase(application)
        .wordDb.wordlistDao()
        .let(::WordRepository)

    private val word: LiveData<String> = liveData {
        repository.readWord()
    }

    val someLiveDataForUi: LiveData<Something> = Transformations.map(word) { word ->
        // Do something with word and return result. The UI code can
        // observe this live data to get the result when it becomes ready.
    }
}
```

To do this in a way that is more similar to your code (just to help with understanding, since this is less concise), you can create a MutableLiveData and publish to the LiveData from your coroutine.

```
class HomeViewModel(application: Application) : ViewModel() {

    private val repository: WordRepository
    private val word = MutableLiveData<String>()

    init {
        val wordDb = WordListDatabase.getDatabase(application)
        val wordDao = wordDb.wordlistDao()
        repository = WordRepository(wordDao)
        viewModelScope.launch {
            word.value = repository.readWord()
        }
    }

    val someLiveDataForUi: LiveData<Something> = Transformations.map(word) { word ->
        // Do something with word and return result. The UI code can
        // observe this live data to get the result when it becomes ready.
    }
}
```

---

If you're not ready to dive into coroutines yet, you can define your DAO to return a LiveData instead of suspending. It will start reading the item from the database and publish it through the live data once it's ready.

```
@Dao
interface WordListDao {
    @Query("SELECT word FROM wordlist WHERE used = 0 ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1")
    fun readWord(): LiveData<String>
}
```

```
class HomeViewModel(application: Application) : ViewModel() {

    private val repository: WordRepository = WordListDatabase.getDatabase(application)
        .wordDb.wordlistDao()
        .let(::WordRepository)

    private val word: LiveData<String> = repository.readWord()

    //...
}
```

Comment: I gave someone else below the correct answer tick as it solves my exact problem. but this is a really good answer to help me lern further too. Thanks so much

Answer (score 1):

The return value is as expected, because [launch](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/launch.html) does always return a `Job` object representing the background process.

I do not know how you want to use the `String` for, but all operations which should be done after receiving the `String` must be moved inside the `Coroutine` or in a function which is called from the `Coroutine`.

```
viewModelScope.launch {
                val word = repository.readWord()
                
                // do stuff with word
                
                // switch to MainThread if needed
                launch(Dispatchers.Main){}
            }
```

Comment: Updated the question a little so it's easier to understand maybe. The word would be a guess that only the Viewmodel ever works with. Possibly coroutines aren't what I need here. Or j need to observe livedata from within the VM?